# how to draw line from mouse marker to fixed point in google maps api?

Tags: google-maps

i want to draw a line from mouse cursor to a fixed point using **google maps api**

i found that code...

i can define the fixed point 
but i couldn't define the mouse position

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCwID2UsBJvwVKEMx_U53brmIC8EOLsBFo&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var length = markers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng));
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }


var x=new google.maps.LatLng(52.395715,4.888916);
var stavanger=new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
var london=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:x,
  zoom:4,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var myTrip=[stavanger,london];
var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
  path:myTrip,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.9,
  strokeWeight:2
  });

flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I retrieve the mouse coordinates?

example 
http://apps.qiblalocator.com/ext/embed/?address=usa

Comment: markers is not defined in your code.

Comment: Your "example" is using v2 of the API, the posted code uses v3.  v2 is deprecated and not recommended for new development as it can be turned off as early as May 2013.

Comment: i put the example for preview only

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the mouse coordinates like this (assuming you have a div with element id "latlgn").

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "mousemove", function(pt) { 
      document.getElementById("latlgn").innerHTML = pt.latLng; 
    });
```

From example in this [thread in the google maps api v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/26076491927f6c85)

Comment: What do you mean by that?  What variables (in your question)?

Comment: i want the mouse position in different variable